# Several PlotViews handling 1 zooming/panning event OxyPlot

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, oxyplot

I need to make synchronous horizontal panning in several PlotView. So when you pan in one Plot vertically and horizontally other plotviews should pan only horizontally. This behaviour is similar to when you make several vertical axes and 1 common horizontal axis. But when you pan exact PlotView it must pan horizontally and vertically (if panning is enabled in axis).